# SIGSEGV, Segmentation Fault con C++ en Code::Blocks

Tags: c++

Estoy agregando nodos a una lista enlazada simple, los nodos guardan dos valores double.

Cuando depuro el programa en `Code::Blocks` me sale un error que dice:

```
"Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault."
```

Luego me avisa en qué sección del código ha detectado el problema, es cuando intento llamar a una función que agrega un nodo desde otra que indica cuántas veces debe hacerlo.

El depurador muestra el error dos veces y luego dice que el programa se cayó.
Este error no impide que corra el programa, pero creo que está causando que algunas cosas posteriores no funcionen como deberían. ¿Cómo podría arreglarlo?

He seguido la recomendación de quitar un puntero como variable global, además de cuidar detalles para evitar que sea nulo, el error perdura, el código va así ahora:

En el `main` las líneas importantes son las siguientes:

```
Nodo *cls_val;
Nodo *n0 = new Nodo;
cls_val = n0;
n0->info = "Inicio de la lista";
Rangos(cls_val);
```

La función `Rangos`es así:

```
void Rangos(Nodo *cb)
{
    double mini = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < clss; i++)
    {
        cb = Agr_Rango(mini, mini+anch, cb);
        cb = cb->sig;
        mini += anch;
    }
}
```

Finalmente, la famosa `Agr_Rangos` donde está la línea conflictiva:

```
Nodo* Agr_Rango(double mnm, double mxm, Nodo *cab)
{
    Nodo *ni, *ptr;
    ni = new Nodo;
    ni->mn = mnm;
    ni->mx = mxm;
    ptr = cab;
    if(ptr == NULL)
    {
        cab = ni;
    }
    else
    {
        while(ptr->sig != NULL) //Aquí señala el problema.
            ptr = ptr->sig;
        ptr->sig = ni;
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: `SIGSEGV` seguramente significa que intentas acceder a memoria no valida; y sin duda se trata de la operación `ptr = cls_val` en que asignas a `ptr` un valor que apunta a memoria no válida. ¿Puedes poner el código completo?: Haría falta conocer dónde se inicializa `cls_val`.

Comment: El código completo es muy largo, la declaración de `cls_val` se hace entre las primeras líneas de código, pues es una variable global. Después de eso, no hay una inicialización, pues pretendo usarlo simplemente como un puntero cabeza, así que se podría decir que la inicializo en el `if` del método `Agr_Rango` que ya compartí.

Comment: Creo que tu problema es que pasas los punteros por copia.

Comment: Le agradezco a todos su ayuda, efectivamente una parte se solucionó enviando el puntero por referencia. Seguía apareciendo segmentation fault, pero lo solucioné con una idea simple que compartiré por si a alguien le llega a servir: hacer un nodo vacío que siempre se sitúe al final de la fila, así las condiciones y ciclos verificarán que cuando el puntero se mueva no termine en ese nodo, en vez de preguntar si topaba con nulo, ahora todo funciona de maravilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SIGSEGV` es el error que el sistema lanza cuando se intenta acceder a memoria no válida.

[Aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12.aspx) puedes ver detalles en MSDN (Inglés) y [aquí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSEGV) detalles en la Wikipedia.

Así pues, en el momento en que `ptr->sig` lanza `SIGSEGV`, la variable `ptr` está apuntando a memoria no válida. La variable `ptr` ha sido asignada en líneas anteriores con el contenido de `cls_val` la cual, mencionas que es una variable global.

Comprueba lo siguiente:

- `cls_val` ha sido inicializada correctamente antes de ser usada.
- `cls_val` contiene valores válidos en el momento de asignarse a `ptr`.
- `cls_val` no apunta a `NULL`, `nullptr` o `0` en el momento de asignarse a `ptr`.
- `cls_val` no es accedida desde otro hilo simultáneamente al acceso realizado desde `Agr_Rango`.
- `cls_val` no es confundida con otra variable local del mismo nombre en otro contexto.

Por otro lado, [evita el uso de variables globales](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad) en la medida de lo posible:

- **Carecen de localidad**: El código es más fácil de comprender cuando su ámbito es limitado. Las variables globales pueden ser leídas o modificadas desde cualquier parte del programa, esto hace difícil razonar sobre su uso o recordar todos los puntos en que se usan.
- **Carecen de control de acceso o verificación de restricciones**: Una variable global puede ser leída o escrita desde cualquier parte del programa, varias reglas acerca de su uso pueden ser olvidadas o violadas.
- **Problemas de concurrencia**: Si las variables globales pueden ser accedidas desde varios hilos, es necesario sincronizarlas. Cuando se trabaja con módulos dinámicamente enlazados que usan variables globales, el sistema resultante puede no ser seguro incluso cuando los módulos lo sean de manera independiente.
- **Contaminación del espacio de nombres**: Las variables globales están en todos los contextos. Puedes acabar usando una variable global cuando creías estar usando una local ¡o viceversa! (ya sea por desconocimiento, escribir mal el nombre u olvidarte de crear la variable local). Además, si enlazas módulos con variables globales cuyo nombre sea igual, si tienes suerte, tendrás errores de enlazado... si no tienes suerte el enlazador considerará las variables como la misma incluso aunque no fuese tu intención.
- **Más problemas en el enlace (en Inglés)**: He traducido los puntos que creía que eran más relevantes para tu problema.

Si quieres una solución más detallada, me temo que necesitaremos el código completo.

---

#### Editado

El problema podría estar en las funciones `Rangos` y `Agr_Rango` en que pasas el puntero a utilizar **por copia**; veamos como ejemplo la función `Rangos` (por ser más corta):

```
void Rangos(Nodo *cb)
{
    double mini = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < clss; i++)
    {
        cb = Agr_Rango(mini, mini+anch, cb);
        cb = cb->sig;
        mini += anch;
    }
}
```

El parámetro `cb` es una copia del puntero `cls_val`, de manera que cuando lo inicializas al valor de `Agr_Rango` lo que estás modificando no es el `cls_val` externo si no su **copia**; para conseguir la funcionalidad que esperas deberás pasar un puntero a puntero o una referencia a puntero:

```
Nodo *cls_val;
Nodo *n0 = new Nodo;
cls_val = n0;
n0->info = "Inicio de la lista";
Rangos(&cls_val); // <--- pasar como PUNTERO!!

void Rangos(Nodo **cb) // <--- puntero a puntero
{
    double mini = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < clss; i++)
    {
        *cb = Agr_Rango(mini, mini+anch, cb); // <-- modificar valor apuntado
        *cb = (*cb)->sig;                     // <-- modificar valor apuntado
        mini += anch;
    }
}
```

Yo personalmente prefiero la versión referencia a puntero:

```
Nodo *cls_val;
Nodo *n0 = new Nodo;
cls_val = n0;
n0->info = "Inicio de la lista";
Rangos(cls_val); // <--- No requiere cambio alguno

void Rangos(Nodo *&cb) // <--- referencia!
{
    double mini = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < clss; i++)
    {
        cb = Agr_Rango(mini, mini+anch, cb); // <--- No requiere cambio
        cb = cb->sig;                        // <--- No requiere cambio
        mini += anch;
    }
}
```

Deberás hacer este cambio tanto en `Rangos` como en `Agr_Rango`. Puedes ver un ejemplo simplificado del que creo que es tu problema [aquí](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/4o22jMw1qZI2STEl):

```
void puntero(int *parametro)
{
    parametro = new int{456};
}

void puntero_a_puntero(int **parametro)
{
    *parametro = new int{789};
}

void referencia_a_puntero(int *&parametro)
{
    parametro = new int{111};
}

int *p = new int{123};

// p no es mocificado, sigue apuntando al valor 123, no a 456
puntero(p);
// p es modificado por puntero, apunta al valor 789
puntero_a_puntero(&p);
// p es modificado por referencia, apunta al valor 111
referencia_a_puntero(p);
```

PD: Ya se que mi ejemplo tiene leaks de memoria, es sólo un ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias por esa respuesta tan detallada. Intenté cambiar un poco el código para quitar ese puntero como variable global y que pasara a ser un parámetro de varias llamadas. Además, ahora inicializo la lista con un nodo vacío para evitar que `ptr` acabe apuntando a `NULL` cuando se le asigna el valor del puntero, pero sigue apareciendo el mismo error. Editaré la pregunta para mostrar el nuevo código.